# jQuery tree traversal get an element that's not a parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get an element by tree traversal but I can't get there. Example HTML:

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="findThis">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="loopThis"></td>
      <td class="loopThis"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="findThis">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="loopThis"></td>
      <td class="loopThis"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Example jQuery/javascript:

```
$('.loopThis').each(function(){
    var findThisClass = $(this).parent().parent().children('.findThis');
});
```

The problem I'm having here is that I this returns all `findThis` classes, but I need to have the parent/closest `findThis` class for each `loopThis`

Comment: sorry what do you mean by closest.. do you mean the previous `fidnThis` of the current `loopThis`

Comment: @ArunPJohny Yes exactly.

Comment: `var findThisClass = $(this).closest('tr').prev('.findThis');`

Comment: For each `.loopThis`, can you write which `.findThis` you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want to find the previous `findThis` element of the current `loopThis` element, you can find the current `tr` element and then its previous `tr` sibling

```
$('.loopThis').each(function(){
    var findThisClass = $(this).closest('tr').prev('.findThis');
});
```

Comment: Thanks exactly what I needed.